# Table name alias in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I use the following commands in netezza SQL to define table name alias while running a query through command line NZSQL

```
\set catgtable 'table_a'
\echo table name is :catgtable
```

and I use the table name alias catgtable wherever required as in:

```
select *
from :catgtable where col1 is not NULL
```

My problem is how to use the alias name in these 2 situations:

1. ```
   select ':catgtable' as table_name, col1,col2
   from table_x
   ```

   This gives me an error, since it requires the actual table name.
2. ```
   select table_name, column_name
   from _v_sys_columns
   where table_name = ':catgtable' and column_name like '%merch_cat_%'
   ```

   Here again the alias: `catgtable` doesn't work and it requires the actual table name.

Let me know if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use the contents of a variable as a literal in nzsql you need to include an additional set of single quotes, escaped with backslashes, around the literal text when you set the variable.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \set tvar '\'BLAH\''
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select :tvar col_alias;
 COL_ALIAS
-----------
 BLAH
(1 row)
```